# remove button under select in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I am working on jQuery. I am using mutltiselect

```
<select id="city" class="multiselect">
  <button class = "....">
  </button>
</select>
```

the button under select is creating dynamically it has no id nothing. Now I would like to remove that button.

I tried like this

```
$("#city.button").remove();
$("#city button").remove();
```

both are not working. Can anyone suggest me how to remove this dynamically created button. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Number 2 should work, but you should not have a button element inside a select

Comment: 1.button inside select is invalid.2. is your select is also generated dynamically?

Comment: Why you want to remove it ?

Comment: Select is not dynamically creating.I am only given in html .

Comment: 1. try to to use the html/js engine with your example. 2. isn't the button a child of the select?

Comment: @Mayank actually by default my select is disabled. I am enabling it on some conditions. For that I have used $("#city").removeAttr("disabled"); . But it's not disabling my drop down. That's why I am removing extra added CSS manually then only it is enabling. But in that process button has also created . Now I am in a process of removing that button

Comment: first show the html screenshot where button is showing?
Button will no show in select so this question is wrong.

Comment: Guys I got it . Actually that button is under td not under select. So i gave id for td. Then applied same remove function. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `<button>` inside `<select>` during the time page is loaded then the browser will simply remove that. But if you are adding a `<button>` dynamically then the code `$("#city button").remove();` works:

```js
 //lets say this code adds the button dynamically
 $("select#city").append('<button>sss</button>');
 //this works then 
 $("#city button").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="city" class="multiselect">
  <button class = "....">
  </button>
</select>
```